# bash script to append file's name at the end of each line in it's file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have some files in a directory:

```
a.csv b.csv c.csv
```

I wanted to write a bash script to add a filename at the end of each line of its file, like:

```
a.csv
line1 ,a
line2, a
line, a

b.csv
line1, b
line2, b
line3, b
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

With only GNU `awk` assuming your files are a few and will not reach the `ARG_MAX` limit:

```bash
gawk '{f=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", f); gsub(/\n/, "_NL_", f)}{{printf "%s, %s\n", $0, f}}' *.csv
```

Or in a shell loop for large number of files:

```bash
for f in *.csv; do
  gawk '{f=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", f); gsub(/\n/, "_NL_", f)}{{printf "%s, %s\n", $0, f}}' "$f"
  done
```

**Notice**: for `gawk` to edit the files(*instead of only printing to terminal*), you need to set the `-i inplace` flag like so:

```bash
gawk -i inplace '{f=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", f); gsub(/\n/, "_NL_", f)}{{printf "%s, %s\n", $0, f}}' *.csv
```

---

If, however, you insist on a pure `bash` script ... Then, you can use this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

simulation="on"

for f in *.csv; do
  fn="${f//$'\n'/_NL_}"
  fn="${fn%\.*}"
  readarray -t tmp < "$f"
  if [ "$simulation" == "off" ]; then
    > "$f"
  fi
  for l in "${tmp[@]}"; do
    if [ "$simulation" == "off" ]; then
      printf "%s, %s\n" "$l" "$fn" >> "$f"
    else
      printf "%s, %s\n" "$l" "$fn"
    fi
    done
  done
```

**Notice**: This will only output to terminal for a dry-run ... To make it edit the files instead, you need to change `simulation="on"` to `simulation="off"`

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` (assuming sanely named files):

```
for f in *.csv; do
  awk '$++NF=o' OFS=', ' o=${f%.*} $f > $f_new
done
```